# Routing port 80 to shiny-server via nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I think I've got this thing nearly 90% of the way there, but entering domain.net brings me to the 'welcome to nginx' landing instead of the shiny-server (at 3838).

```
Nginx config file:

    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;

            # SSL configuration
            #
            # listen 443 ssl default_server;
            # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

            root /srv/shiny-server/;

            # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
            index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

            server_name _;

            location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/;
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:3838/ $scheme://$host/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
         }
    }


Shiny-server config file:

    preserve_logs true;
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

'

```
$sudo netstat -nlp | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1159/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1159/nginx -g daemo

$curl http://127.0.0.1
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: I added port 80 to my aws security profile, now I can't load shiny-server at even :3838, and to make things worse, when I turn off nginx, I still can't access via 3838. How did adding that single port nuke my entire setup.

Comment: The output of your netstat command shows that you don't have nginx listening on port 3838. Do you a link to shiny-server.conf in nginx's sites-enabled folder? Edit: And why do you want a root directive in the proxy config?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are trying to do this with nginx. Why not DNAT port 80 to port 3838 in the PREROUTING chain of the nat table? `iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3838`

Comment: @cburn Nginx was the first solution I found, I'll give your solution a try. I also fixed a couple typos in the configfiles

Comment: iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?) Is this using a package I need to install?

Comment: You probably just need to enable ip forwarding. `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/ip_forward` or in /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need check if shiny-server is running and listening on the TCP port 3838. Use this command

> netstat -antp | grep 3838

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3838            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 172.31.92.209:3838      73.61.24.11:53083       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.31.92.209:3838      73.61.24.11:53082       TIME_WAIT   -
 Looks like it is listening on :3838